# Haskell - How to use <- in where clauses

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
foo :: Int -> IO ()
foo n = do
    x <- bar 6
    print "foo running..."
    print x


bar :: Int -> IO Int
bar n = do
    print "bar running..."
    return (n*2)
```

Now I want to put the "x <- bar 6" part in a where clause, like this:

```
foo :: Int -> IO ()
foo n = do
    print "foo running..."
    print x
    where
        x <- bar 6

bar :: Int -> IO Int
bar n = do
    print "bar running..."
    return (n*2)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't allowed. A `where` clause doesn't impose an evaluation order, which is necessary for most Monads, such as `IO`. If this were possible, when would `bar 6` be executed relative to the two `print`s? Would it be at the very beginning or in between them?

Answer (score 5):

> How do I do this?

It doesn't make sense. I'm sorry.

The following, in a `do` block:

```
a <- b
c
```

is equivalent to:

```
b >>= (\a -> c)
```

So `a <- b` alone, would be equivalent to: `b >>= (\a ->)` which is a grammar error.

There's no need for you to store `x` in a `where` clause anyway. In your program:

```
foo :: Int -> IO ()
foo n = do
    x <- bar 6
    ...
```

after `x <- bar 6`, you can reuse `x` everywhere within the `do` block.